# How to make image clickable

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

```
<div className="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
    <li>
      <img src='https://i.imgur.com/fe0T4nw.png' onClick="https://arizonaatwork.com" />
    </li>
</div>
```

In my project I am importing an image and on the onclick I want the image to take them to a URL. How can I get this done?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `a` tag:

```
<li><a href='https://arizonaatwork.com'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/fe0T4nw.png'/></a></li>
```

Comment: Hi, the image is not clickable. Here is the method you gave me.              <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
        <li><a href='https://arizonaatwork.com'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/fe0T4nw.png'/></a></li>
        </div>

Answer (score 0):

Working example:
You need to add "a" tag before image

```
<div className="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
<li>
  <a href="https://i.imgur.com/fe0T4nw.png"><img src='https://i.imgur.com/fe0T4nw.png' onClick="https://arizonaatwork.com" /></a>
</li>
```